# What sources of granular wind data over the continental US are available?

Tags: data, weather

I am looking for publicly or commercially available wind data at altitudes ranging from 0 feet to 40,000 feet over the continental United States.

Which data sources should I look at? Which one is available at the finest resolution (both spatially and temporally) possible? How was this data measured or modeled?

Answer (score 2):

This best resource for publicly available data is going to be from the National Renewable Energy Laboratory, but that isn't going to cover all the altitudes you are looking for.  [NREL wind data page](http://www.nrel.gov/gis/data_wind.html)

NREL's data is based on a model developed by AWS Truepower, which sells a more comprehensive dataset, but I don't know if it will cover everything you need. [AWS Truepower](http://www.awstruepower.com/)

NREL's site also has some links to other resources, covering different geographies and altitudes, such as the [US Department of Energy](http://www.windpoweringamerica.gov/wind_maps.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this post is by any means relevant to GIS. Anyway, [this link](http://esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/reanalysis) has retrospective wind data for the US.

Please select product of choice and you will find detailed info and citations at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[This really cool animated windflow](http://hint.fm/wind/) map says it uses data from the [National Digital Forecast Database](http://ndfd.weather.gov/technical.htm).